# The return type isn't a widget as required by the closures context

Tags: flutter, provider

I try to complete tutorial and I get this error (look at the picture).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:provider_architecture/core/viewmodels/login_model.dart';
import 'package:provider_architecture/locator.dart';

class LoginView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<LoginModel>(
      builder: (context) => locator<LoginModel>(), // the error is here
      child: Consumer<LoginModel>(
        builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: just replace builder with **create** and also check out package doc. to stay up to date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
builder: (context) => locator<LoginModel>()
```

to:

```
create: (context) => locator<LoginModel>()
```