# Flutter: Return type Widget? isn't a Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code which is giving me lots of null safety errors:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const int largeScreenSize = 1366;
const int mediumScreenSize = 768;
const int smallScreenSize = 360;
const int customScreenSize = 1100;

class ResponsiveWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget? largeScreen;
  final Widget? mediumScreen;
  final Widget? smallScreen;

  const ResponsiveWidget({
    Key? key,
    @required this.largeScreen,
    this.mediumScreen,
    this.smallScreen,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

In `build` I am using a `LayoutBuilder` like this:

```
return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        double _width = constraints.maxWidth;
        if (_width > largeScreenSize) {
          return largeScreen;
        } else if (_width < largeScreenSize && _width >= mediumScreenSize) {
          return mediumScreen ?? largeScreen;
        } else {
          return smallScreen ?? largeScreen;
        }
      },
    );
```

But all the screen references are giving error:

> The return type 'Widget?' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.

So if I remove the `?` and make the widgets `largeScreen`, `mediumScreen`, `smallScreen` non-nullable then in constructor I get error:

> The parameter 'largeScreen' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
> Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.

So null or not null, I am getting error in both cases.

Comment: Did you try replacing builder :(context with create . Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182682/the-return-type-isnt-a-widget-as-required-by-the-closures-context

Comment: @Muhtar It says `The named parameter 'create' isn't defined.` create was added in provider, right? I am not using provider at all.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround

```
else if (_width < largeScreenSize && _width >= mediumScreenSize) {
          return mediumScreen as Widget ?? largeScreen  as Widget;
        } else {
          return smallScreen as Widget ?? largeScreen as Widget;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i got solution like this

```
if (_width >= largeScreenSize) {
      return largeScreen as Widget;
    } else if (_width < largeScreenSize && _width >= mediumScreenSize) {
      return mediumScreen ?? largeScreen as Widget;
    } else {
      return smallScreen ?? largeScreen as Widget;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should always return a Widget, **You are returning a null at the last else**, try adding an Empty Container fallback like:

```dart
return LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
        double _width = constraints.maxWidth;

        if (_width > largeScreenSize) {
          return largeScreen;
        } else if (_width < largeScreenSize && _width >= mediumScreenSize) {
          return mediumScreen ?? largeScreen;
        }

        // Default return
        return smallScreen ?? largeScreen ?? Container();
    },
);
```

Comment: Did you try this code? If _width > largeScreenSize and largeScreen is null it would be returning a null. This code should not work unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

You get this problem as the 3 of them may be null so there is no last default widget to avoid returning null.

After non-nullable update `@required` is now `required`. It seems you want `LargeScreen` to be required. So you can fix that with this code.

```dart
class ResponsiveWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget largeScreen;
  final Widget? mediumScreen;
  final Widget? smallScreen;

  const ResponsiveWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.largeScreen,
    this.mediumScreen,
    this.smallScreen,
  }) : super(key: key);
```